# from object how to retrieve particular key and values, only in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In object the values are created as my inputput values object , but i need to retrieve the values particular key values like start with "key" and i need only JavaScript and not with JSON concept

Input Object

```
object = {key_11: "12d", item_12: "a2324", key_16: "34|aa"},
 {key_14: "345|w", key_21: "a|b", key_12: "56|asa|45", item_16: "66"},
 {item_14: "AA|BB, key_15: "44|BB", item_21: "WW"},
 {key_25: "25|a|aa|",  item_01: "999",  key_05: "234"}
```

output Object

```
object = {key_11: "12d", key_16: "34|aa", key_14: "345|w", key_21: "a|b", key_12: >"56|asa|45", key_25: "25|a|aa|", key_05: "234"}
```

Appreciate your help

Comment: Your object syntax is incorrect. Do you mean you have an **array of objects**?

Comment: Didn't your object throw any errors?

Answer (score 2):

If you fix up your syntax issues and put your objects into an array, you can use array methods to help you achieve this.

To achieve this, you can convert each object in your array into a key-value pair array using `Object.entries()`. You can then use this to then `.filter()` out the entries which don't `.startsWith()` "key". Finally, you can rebuild your object of keys value pairs using `Object.fromEntries()`, which you can then spread into the accumulated object using the spread syntax (`...`):

```js
const object = [{
    key_11: "12d",
    item_12: "a2324",
    key_16: "34|aa"
  },
  {
    key_14: "345|w",
    key_21: "a|b",
    key_12: "56|asa|45",
    item_16: "66"
  },
  {
    item_14: "AA|BB",
    key_15: "44|BB",
    item_21: "WW"
  },
  {
    key_25: "25|a|aa|",
    item_01: "999",
    key_05: "234"
  }
];


const res = object.reduce(
  (a, o) => ({ ...a,
    ...Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(o).filter(([k]) => k.startsWith('key')))
  }), {});

console.log(res);
```

Please do keep in mind that `Object.fromEntries()` is currently in draft mode, for something a little more browser compatible, you can use the following:

```js
const object = [{
    key_11: "12d",
    item_12: "a2324",
    key_16: "34|aa"
  },
  {
    key_14: "345|w",
    key_21: "a|b",
    key_12: "56|asa|45",
    item_16: "66"
  },
  {
    item_14: "AA|BB",
    key_15: "44|BB",
    item_21: "WW"
  },
  {
    key_25: "25|a|aa|",
    item_01: "999",
    key_05: "234"
  }
];


const res = object.reduce(
  (a, o) => ({ ...a,
    ...Object.entries(o).filter(([k]) => k.indexOf('key') === 0).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => ({ ...acc,
      [k]: v
    }), {})
  }), {});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: those value are my local Storage values and i want to display only with starts with "key"  and i'm using this way to display using for loop  so it displaying all the  local Storage values ,but i want to display only  only with starts with "key"                                            
   for (var i = 0; i <= localStorage.length; i++) { 
  var key = localStorage.key(i);
  var value = localStorage.getItem(key);
}            if

Comment: @user10540420 your original question has nothing to do with local storage. Ask a new question which specifies this new question. Make sure to provide your code and your expected result

Comment: i'm sorry , i didn't understand your code , i'm new to javascript, after filter i'm looking to an variable

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to combine array of objects into one, consider the following:

```js
var obj = [{key_11:"12d",item_12:"a2324",key_16:"34|aa"},{key_14:"345|w",key_21:"a|b",key_12:"56|asa|45",item_16:"66"},{item_14:"AA|BB",key_15:"44|BB",item_21: "WW"},{key_25:"25|a|aa|",item_01:"999",key_05:"234"}];

var final = {};
obj.forEach(a => Object.entries(a).forEach(e => e[0].indexOf('key') > -1 ? Object.assign(final, {[e[0]]: e[1]}):0));
console.log(final);
```

Comment: Yes sorry, I did use it initially, also I'd like to tell your answer is awesome

Answer (score 0):

first of all in your object initialization there has a typo

> key_12: >"56|asa|45"

so remove the extra > symbol and retrieve value with key

> console.log(object.key_12);

```js
var object = {key_11: "12d", key_16: "34|aa", key_14: "345|w", key_21: "a|b", key_12: "56|asa|45", key_25: "25|a|aa|", key_05: "234"};

console.log(object.key_12);
```

If I didn`t misunderstood hope it will solve your issue. thank you

Answer (score -1):

Your object is not well syntaxed consider using an array instead :

```js
arrayOfObjects = [{key_11: "12d", item_12: "a2324", key_16: "34|aa"}, {key_14: "345|w", key_21: "a|b", key_12: "56|asa|45", item_16: "66"}, {item_14: "AA|BB", key_15: "44|BB", item_21: "WW"}, {key_25: "25|a|aa|",  item_01: "999",  key_05: "234"}]
```